# Notable claim made on BBC News channel, how might I find the exact wording?

Tags: discussion

[A claim](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/42682/5337) was made by a BBC News reported in a TV broadcast on the BBC News channel.  I would consider that notable, but the broadcast is not available on BBC iPlayer, and not repeated in their web reporting on the same topic.  How can I retrieve the exact wording?

Comment: Doesn't the BBC subtitle *everything*? There are two venues I'd look into: the subtitle sharing community and the video hosters. If the claim is a big one, I'd guess someone will upload a recording, ripped stream etc. If you have a UK address, I think you should also feel entitled to ask them directly (paying for it and all).

Comment: @LangLangC The program in question was a regular daily news broadcast, hour long, claim near the end.  Not a famous documentary or anything like that.  I would be surprised to find it on either.

Comment: Sth along those lines? http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/futuremedia/accessibility/subtitling_guides/retrieving.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Historically, our answer to questions like this has been "Find another source".

If you can't find anyone else quoting the same (or a similar) claim, then it likely isn't widely believed, and perhaps wasn't notable in the first place.

Comment: I would add that if the BBC reported it, it's virtually guaranteed to have been reported on by other outlets as well -- even if only "the BBC made this outrageous claim, let's point and laugh".